# Use of Multiple Cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to update one a table with values from another table. the first table `Tbl_test_details` has `customer_id` ,`pr_no` and `tests` and few more columns and second table `tbl_tests` has `tests`. for each `pr_no` in `tbl_test_details` I want to add all the values in `tests` from `tbl_tests`.
I tried to do it with cursors but its not working. It inserts records for only first `pr_no` and exits. Need help

Update: There is one more problem that the `pr_no` is repeated `tbl_test_deatils` and some `test` values exist already, so some insertion might fail because of the primary key (pr_no + `tests`)

````
   DECLARE @test nvarchar(180)
   DECLARE @prno nvarchar(50)
   DECLARE @dte date
   DECLARE @tst nvarchar(180)
       DECLARE cr_testd CURSOR FOR
       SELECT cust_id,pr_no,date 
       FROM tbl_Test_Details;
       DECLARE cr_tests CURSOR FOR
       SELECT test_name 
       FROM tbl_tests
   OPEN cr_testd
   FETCH NEXT FROM cr_testd into @cid,@prno,@dte
   OPEN cr_tests
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
       FETCH NEXT FROM cr_tests into @tst
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
       BEGIN
           Insert into tbl_Test_Details values(@cid,@tst,@prno,@dte)
           IF (@@ROWCOUNT <= 0)
               BEGIN
                   BREAK
               END
       FETCH NEXT FROM cr_tests into @tst
       END
   FETCH NEXT FROM cr_tests into @tst
   END

   CLOSE cr_test
   DEALLOCATE cr_test```

Current State of Tables
Tbl_Test_details         Tbl_Tests
|--------------------|     |-----------|
|pr_no   c_id  Tests |     |  Tests    |
|--------------------|     |-----------|
|1        100   MDD  |     |  MDD      |
|1        100   FDT  |     |  FDT      | 
|2        101   DMC  |     |  DMC      |
                           |  CDD      |


Result Table
tbl_test_details
|--------------------|    
|pr_no   c_id  Tests |    
|--------------------|    
|1        100   MDD  |    
|1        100   FDT  |
|1        100   DMC  |
|1        100   CDD  |    
|2        101   MDD  | 
|2        101   FDT  | 
|2        101   DMC  | 
|2        101   CDD  |
````

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working? provide more details like:  any error message, or it runs successfully without inserting any data, and add some sample data to the question.

Comment: Single cursor through you can handle this situation.  follow the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Update of one table based on values in cursor of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564096/sql-update-of-one-table-based-on-values-in-cursor-of-another-table)

Comment: @Yeou I have updated the question. Please check

Comment: @chandukomati It deals with updating rows where one condition is met. In my case the condition is where `pr_no` and I need change for all the `pr_no`. Please correct me if am wrong. I am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the perfect answer, it has perfomance issues still I was able to perform the operation successfully.

```
DECLARE @cid int
DECLARE @tn int
DECLARE @prno nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @dte date
DECLARE @trn int
DECLARE @tst nvarchar(180)
DECLARE cr_testd CURSOR FOR
SELECT cust_id,pr_no,date 
FROM tbl_Test_Details;
DECLARE cr_tests CURSOR FOR
SELECT test_name 
FROM tbl_tests
DECLARE @trn=(select count(test_name) from tbl_tests)
OPEN cr_testd
FETCH NEXT FROM cr_testd into @cid,@prno,@dte
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    OPEN cr_tests
    FETCH NEXT FROM cr_tests into @tst
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
        SET @tn=(select count(*) from tbl_Test_Details where pr_no=@prno)
        IF(@tn = @trn)
        BEGIN           
            BREAK;
        END
        Insert into tbl_Test_Details values(@cid,@tst,0,0,@prno,@dte)
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH

        END CATCH
    FETCH NEXT FROM cr_tests into @tst
    END
    CLOSE cr_tests
FETCH NEXT FROM cr_testd into @cid,@prno,@dte
END
CLOSE cr_testd
DEALLOCATE cr_testd
DEALLOCATE cr_tests
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow this url : [SQL Update of one table based on values in cursor of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10564096/12133934)

i think this will helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cursors` you can write a query using `Cross Join` to fetch `for each pr_no in tbl_test_details all the values in tests from tbl_tests` and `Except` to insert new non existing records in `tbl_test_details` as:

```
insert into @Tbl_Test_details (pr_no,c_id,Tests)
select  TD.pr_no,
       TD.c_id,
       TS.Tests
from @Tbl_Test_details TD
cross Join @Tbl_Tests TS
except
select  TD.pr_no,
       TD.c_id,
       TD.Tests
from @Tbl_Test_details TD
```

[sample code here..](https://rextester.com/ZVFD69589)

Comment: Thanks you for the help, The table contains more columns ,I just mentioned the important ones. Can you help me further